# Creating 2 button menu for lcd Arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupt, lcd

I would like to create a menu for my lcd with Arduino. I want to use 2 buttons - one for scrolling down and one for selecting items. Pressing first button again will go back to menu. The problem is that, if I insert that line in my code: `while(digitalRead(menu) == LOW);`
my program is waiting only for first button to be pressed, so the second button doesn't work. But if I don't insert that line both buttons are working fine, but the text on the lcd is flashing.
The pseudo code  would be like that:

if first button pressed:

->go to first menu item

-->if second button pressed(interrput?):

--->display content

if first button pressed:

->go to second menu item

-->if second button pressed (interrupt?):

---> display content

How can I write my program to wait for an interrupt instead of waiting and doing nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void setup
{
 //...
}
```

Just do not change the display if you do not have to.
Something along these lines maybe:

```
#define NUM_ITEMS 5

int itemShown = -1;
int item2show = 0;

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(button1pin) == LOW)
  {
       item2show++;
       if(item2show>=NUM_ITEMS)
           item2show = 0;
  } else { 
    // if button2 do it
  }

  if (item2show != itemShown) 
  {
     showItem(item2show);
     itemShown = item2Show;
  }
}
}
```